# Default document in IIS

Tags: iis

I have previously used parameters when setting Default document in IIS.

Example list of default documents:

- Default.aspx?control=start
- Default.asp
- Default.html

And when I go to **www.mypage.com** i end up on **www.mypage.com/Default.aspx?control=start** But this no longer work. I now end up on **www.mypage.com/Default.aspx**

Any ideas on what might be wrong? security updates from microsoft?

Running: Windows Server 2003, IIS 6, ASP.net 2.0

Comment: Please see: http://serverfault.com/questions/91687/how-do-i-add-a-querystring-to-a-default-document-in-iis7

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it doesn't work with IIS 7 or IIS 7.5 to begin with. Since you are saying that it worked with IIS 6, I checked with IIS 6 as well...

I created a default document in IIS 6 called... test.aspx?test=123

When I browsed http://localhost, I was NOT redirected to http://localhost/test.aspx?test=123... although IIS would assume that you want this page and give you an appropriate output. I just checked from this code... and as expected it totally ignored test query string.

If I pass anything from my browser, the code works as expected.

In a nutshell, what I want to say is... Default document does not work with Query string. Although, it is pretty easy to achieve in code. Just do a Server.Transfer or Response.Redirect and attach the querystring if it is not already available.

HTH,
Rahul